# java get http response from target (302 - object moved) - hppt https protocols

Tags: java, http, https, httpurlconnection

I have the following situation that I'm still not able to manage:

1. I wrote a java class to read a http response from a site that receive POST parameters
2. I use HttpURLConnection and pass the input parameters
3. the result obtained is another form that redirect to another page (via HTTPS) to which I have to pass a username and a password and an hodden value. this page show the result in a target page (that is the firt url)
4. I made a call to this other page via HTTPS (HttpsURLConnection) and obtained a http 302 response code

I'm not able to reach the result page, since the followredirect option doesn't work when the protocol change (from http to https)

Can anyone help me please?
Hope I have succesfully explained.

Thanks in advance for support and regards.